# JSF 2.0 and Spring Security User authentication to login webapp

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security

im trying out to build a web application. it must have contain a login page. i couldn't find  any example with jsf 2.0 and spring security 3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this one is still valid for version 3.1, principle shoud be the same http://ocpsoft.com/java/acegi-spring-security-jsf-login-page/